# Wix Custom element is working only when it keeps its standard tag "wix-default-custom-element"

Tags: javascript, css, velo

So as you can read from the title, I have tried to use a Custom Element in WIX. When I used the template by wix, it worked perfectly well. When I just try to change the tag name however, the element doesn't show anything afterwards. Changing text such as H2_TEXT works

Here is the code by wix if somebody needs it (this does work for me):

```js
// To debug this code, open wixDefaultCustomElement.js in Developer Tools.

const IMAGE_URL = 'https://wix.to/vUBXBKU';
const H2_TEXT = 'This is a Custom Element';
const H3_1_TEXT = 'View its code by clicking the Settings button and pasting the Server URL into a new browser tab.';
const H3_2_TEXT = 'Explore this code and use it as a reference to create your own element.';
const DEBUG_TEXT = 'Loading the code for Custom Element \'wix-default-custom-element\'. To debug this code, open wixDefaultCustomElement.js in Developer Tools.';

const createImage = () => {
  const imageElement = document.createElement('img');
  imageElement.src = IMAGE_URL;
  imageElement.id = 'wdce-image';
  return imageElement;
};

const createH2 = () => {
  const h2Element = document.createElement('h2');
  h2Element.textContent = H2_TEXT;
  h2Element.id = 'wdce-h2';
  return h2Element;
};

const createH3 = (id, text) => {
  const h3Element = document.createElement('h3');
  h3Element.id = id;
  h3Element.textContent = text;
  return h3Element;
};

const createTextContainer = () => {
  const textContainer = document.createElement('div');
  textContainer.id = 'wdce-text-container';
  textContainer.appendChild(createH2());
  textContainer.appendChild(createH3('wdce-h3-1', H3_1_TEXT));
  textContainer.appendChild(createH3('wdce-h3-2', H3_2_TEXT));
  return textContainer;
};

const createImageContainer = () => {
  const imageContainer = document.createElement('div');
  imageContainer.id = 'wdce-image-container';
  imageContainer.appendChild(createImage());
  return imageContainer;
};

const createStyle = () => {
  const styleElement = document.createElement('style');
  styleElement.innerHTML = `
    wix-default-custom-element {
        background-color: #f0f4f7;
        display: flex;
        width: 100%;
        justify-content: center;
      }

    #wdce-image-container {
        width: 35%;
        max-width: 165px;
        display: flex;
        margin: 0 20px 0 30px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    #wdce-image {
        width: 100%;
        min-width: 100px;
    }

    #wdce-text-container {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        width: 65%;
        justify-content: center;
        max-width: 314px;
        min-width: 200px;
    }

    #wdce-h2 {
        font-family: 'HelveticaNeueW01-45Ligh, HelveticaNeueW02-45Ligh, HelveticaNeueW10-45Ligh, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, ãƒ¡ã‚¤ãƒªã‚ª, meiryo, ãƒ’ãƒ©ã‚®ãƒŽè§’ã‚´ pro w3, hiragino kaku gothic pro, sans-serif',
        font-size: 16px;
        font-weight: 500;
        letter-spacing: 0.89px;
        color: #32536a;
        margin: 0 0 16px 0;
    }

    #wdce-h3-1, #wdce-h3-2 {
        font-family: 'HelveticaNeueW01-45Ligh, HelveticaNeueW02-45Ligh, HelveticaNeueW10-45Ligh, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, ãƒ¡ã‚¤ãƒªã‚ª, meiryo, ãƒ’ãƒ©ã‚®ãƒŽè§’ã‚´ pro w3, hiragino kaku gothic pro, sans-serif',
        font-size: 14px;
        font-weight: 300;
        line-height: 1.43;
        color: #162d3d;
        margin: 0 0 8px 0;
    }
    `;
  return styleElement;
};

class WixDefaultCustomElement extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    console.log(DEBUG_TEXT);
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    this.appendChild(createStyle());
    this.appendChild(createImageContainer());
    this.appendChild(createTextContainer());
  }
}
customElements.define('wix-default-custom-element', WixDefaultCustomElement);
```

Now you might say, "well, that's easy: just change the tag name in customElements.define()", but that doesn't work. I have also tried changing the name in createStyle from wix-default-custom-element to custom-Output.

Like this (that doesn't work):

```
const createStyle = () => {
  const styleElement = document.createElement('style');
  styleElement.innerHTML = `
    #custom-Output {       //doesn't work with #customElement1 (the id) either
        background-color: #f0f4f7;
        display: flex;
        width: 100%;
        justify-content: center;
      }
```

and

```
customElements.define('custom-Output', WixDefaultCustomElement);
```

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1):

The tag name defined in the code needs to match the one defined in the Wix Editor UI. Select your Custom Element in the editor, click Choose source, and then change the tag name there as well.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! However, that is something I already tried. I'm sorry if it was a bit misleading, but for me it was clear to change the tag when changing define(). So that is sadly not the answer, I actually tried that again today.